# FxPlug 2.0 templates not showing up in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, final, cut

I've installed FxPlug 2.0, but no templates are showing up in Xcode 4 when I select "new project". How can I make the templates appear?

Answer (score 1):

The templates don't yet work with Xcode 4. You can use one of the examples in /Developer/Examples/FxPlug/ as a starting point, though. Also, projects created in Xcode 3 with the templates work in Xcode 4.